# js. array.indexOf after using delete

Tags: javascript

First of all - I know that I should use splice to delete elemnts from array to avoid empty spaces.

But I'm just curious. indexOf uses strong typing(===) so why it fails to find index of undefined?

```
var test_arr = [1, 2, 3];
delete test_arr[1];
console.log('indexOf', test_arr.indexOf(undefined));
console.log('check by index:', test_arr[1] === undefined);
```

Comment: Because the *value* `undefined` and the *state* of not having a value defined are two different things.

Comment: `indexOf` skips holes: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.indexof , step 11c .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little weird to explain but... [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is both a *value* and a *state*.

When you do `delete test_arr[1];`, you are *deleting* that index.  `test_arr[1]` no longer exists, it's not defined.  When you try to access it, you'll get back the value `undefined` because that its *state*.

When you do `.indexOf()`, it searches over the *values*.  `test_arr[1]` doesn't have a value.

For an interesting experiment, try this: `test_arr[1] = undefined;` and then do `test_arr.indexOf(undefined)`.